# How Can add a JSON Data to Array in JAVA

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have an project and I'm trying to convey to data from JSON Array to normal array. But I could not this. Can you help me if you know which and where code I add to in my project. My Main Activity file is here

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView tvData;
private String[] stringArray;
protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private NavigationView mNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bilgi);
    setupToolbar();
    initNavigationDrawer();
    new JSONTask().execute("http://192.168.1.36:8080/urunler/kategori_goster.php");

}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>

{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line="";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parrentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("uyelerimiz");
            StringBuffer finalBufferedData = new StringBuffer();
            for(int i=0;i<parrentArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject finalObject = parrentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String year = finalObject.getString("kategori_adi");
                finalBufferedData.append(year + " \n");
            }

            return finalBufferedData.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(connection !=null)
            {
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            try {
                if(reader !=null)
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        tvData.setText(result);

    }
}
```

JSON is working whitout any problem. I want to add my JSON data to my "    private String[] stringArray;"

Here is how the JSON is formatted:

```
{  
   "uyelerimiz":[  
      {  
         "kategori_adi":"Bilgisayar"
      },
      {  
         "kategori_adi"         ‌​:"Cep Telefonu"
      },
      {  
         "kategori_adi":"Saglik"
      },
      {  
         "kategori_adi":"Kirtas‌​iye"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: {"uyelerimiz":[{"kategori_adi":"Bilgisayar"},{"kategori_adi":"Cep Telefonu"},{"kategori_adi":"Saglik"},{"kategori_adi":"Kirtasiye"}]} like this.

Comment: can you send a code here ? how wil it be ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private String[] parseJson(String response){
    try {
        JSONObject lJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray lJsonArray = lJsonObject.getJSONArray("uyelerimiz");
        String[] lResult = new String[lJsonArray.length()];
        for (int index = 0;index<lJsonArray.length();index++){
            lResult[index] = lJsonArray.getJSONObject(index).getString("kategori_adi");
        }
        return lResult;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: how am i call this function ? i want to define "private String[] stringArray;"

Comment: if my json strig was like this : {  
   "uyelerimiz":[  
      {  "id":"1"
         "kategori_adi":"Bilgisayar"
      },
      {  "id":"2"
         "kategori_adi"         ‌​:"Cep Telefonu"
      },
      {  "id":"3"
         "kategori_adi":"Saglik"
      },
      {  "id":"4"
         "kategori_adi":"Kirtas‌​iye"
      }
   ]
} what will we change in your code ?